# How do I join a list in Groovy (in SmartThings state object)?

Tags: groovy, smartthings

This is for a Samsung SmartThings smart app. I've never used Groovy outside of this context, so I'm not sure if this is a quirk of SmartThings or Groovy. It seems that the following should work, but I keep getting a runtime error:

```
def initialize() {
    state.ALL_MODES = ['standby', 'home', 'away']
    state.ALL_MODES_STR = state.All_MODES.join(", ")
}
```

I get the following error in the SmartThings IDE simulator:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method join() on null object
```

I am able to output `state.ALL_MODES` just fine, but when I attempt to `join()` it, I get this error. What am I missing here?

Comment: are you able to output `state.ALL_MODES` inside `initialize` method?

Comment: @Matt, where and how state is defined?

Comment: The join method is correct. Try state.ALL_MODES_STR = state?.All_MODES.join(", ") the ? will suppress the NullPointerException. Your state variable is probably not initialized yet. Can you share the documentation or example you are using to write this?